# Rails 4 get fields liked in this month

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going to show only featured posts based on likes in this month. The algorithm is simple - Get likes from this month and order by most liked post desc.

At this time I have three models:

Likes:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :chapter
  scope :this_month, -> { where(created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month) }
end
```

Content of post - Chapter

```
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
  belongs_to :fanfic

  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked
end
```

And posts - Fanfic

```
class Fanfic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :chapters
  has_many :votes, through: :chapters
  has_many :tags, through: :fanfic_tags
  has_many :fanfic_tags

  # Cover photo
  has_attached_file :cover, styles: { medium: "900x300>", thumb: "300x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing_cover.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :cover, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

In controller I get likes from this month:

```
@likes = Vote.this_month.map(&:id)
@fanfic_featured = Fanfic.all().limit(5)
```

And... I'm stuck here. How can I get fanfics basing on relationship? The fanfic has votes though chapters (chapter has votes, fanfic has chapters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the top 5 list of fanfics that have the most amount of votes created during a certain range:

```
Fanfic.joins(:votes)
  .where(votes: {created_at: Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now.end_of_month}
  .group("fanfics.id")
  .order("count(fanfics.id) DESC")
  .limit(5)
```